# How to hide a Row widget within a Column widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code which displays a Column within an Alert. The Row displays a break value in minutes. If the variable (break1, break2 etc) is 0, I don't want to display that Row. How do I do this? Thanks.

```
content: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 38,
          child: Text(
            'Break 1:',
            style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 62,
          child: Text(
            '$break1 minutes',
            style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 38,
          child: Text(
            'Break 2:',
            style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 62,
          child: Text(
            '$break2 minutes',
            style: TextStyle(color: kBodyText, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Row inside Visibility Widget and set visible to true or false  as per requirement.

```
 Visibility(
     visible:
         !state.getListApiCalled ? true : false,
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                      ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).hp(6)),
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    strokeWidth: 5,
                                  )),
                            ),
```

Comment: what is `getListApiCalled` ?

Comment: getListApiCalled is a bool value used in my state class, you can use anything else instead. like as asked in question if value of beark1 variable is 0 then:
visible : break1==0?false:true

Answer (score 0):

Use [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html).

`visible:false` is used to hide specific widget.

So the code looked like this:

```
   Visibility(visible:false, child:Row());
```